# Why does the `R` pipe operator `|>` not work in the reactive programming using Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I want to use the pipe operator `|>` in the latest version of `R` while doing reactive programming with `Shiny`. For example, when I use the `|>` in the `server` function like so:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("age", "How old are you?"),
    textOutput("message")
)

server <- function(input, output, server) {
    message <- paste0("You are ", input$age) |> reactive({})
    output$message <- renderText(message())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I get this error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4346
Warning: Error in : `env` must be an environment
  56: <Anonymous>
Error : `env` must be an environment
```

This error is fixed when I make slight changes in my server function like so:

```
server <- function(input, output, server) {
        message <- reactive({paste0("You are ", input$age, " years old")})
        output$message <- renderText(message())
}
```

However, I would like to be able to use the pipe operator in my `Shiny` apps. What is wrong with the way I use `|>` in my shiny app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are passing an empty expression `{}` to `reactive`'s first argument (x argument: `reactive(x = {})`).

With your above code the pipe `|>` passes it's expression to `reactive`'s second argument `env`, which results in the error you get. See `?reactive`

This works:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("age", "How old are you?"),
  textOutput("message")
)

server <- function(input, output, server) {
  message <- paste0("You are ", input$age) |> reactive()
  output$message <- renderText(message())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I thought `reactive` should always be used with `{}`. What is the difference between `reactive({})` and `reactive()`? :)

Comment: The difference is described [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Paren.html) (see the examples). { returns the result of the last expression evaluated. In the above case `NULL`, which is passed to `reactive`'s x argument.

Comment: Do you know when I should and should not use `{}` with `reactive()`?

Comment: Joe Cheng explains his motivation of using curly braces [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/help-understanding-shiny-function-syntax-expression-objects-and-curly-brackets/22807/3). The link to the videos over there is down, but you can find them [here](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/shiny-dev-con-2016/) now. I don't think I can come up with a better explanation than him.